# Modeling rates with complex survey data

Tags: poisson-regression, survey-weights

I have data derived from a stratified, cluster random sample with post-stratification weights (corresponding to the inverse probability of response). These are person-level data.

Let's say I want to use (Poisson) regression to analyze rates of assault using these data, where the numerator is the number of people reporting an assault and the denominator (exposure) is the total number of people surveyed. I want the results to account for the weights and survey design.

My idea is to collapse the data into rows, where a row corresponds to all people who share the same covariates and PSU. Each row would have the aggregate number of assaults experienced by the group as the numerator, and the total N of people in the group as the denominator. I would then sum together all the survey weights of persons in each row.

Is this method valid? Are there alternatives I should know about? Any citations or examples of this used in published work?